# Aspnet core 1.0.0-preview2-003121 and wwwroot

Tags: asp.net-core

I just updated my VS.Net 2015 to Update3 and installed the latest asp.net core preview.

I created a simple, empty website and added my controller, just to play.

Then, I created a simple html file with javascript to consume the json the aforementioned controller serves. I put this html page in the wwwroot folder (as I always did so far, RC1 style).

When I hit "dotnet run", and the console confirms the project is running, if I open in my browser

http://localhost:5000

the page is blank. No html at all.
But, if I use

http://localhost:5000/index.html everything is ok, I can see my page that consume the controller's json.

How to restore the default wwwroot documents and files?

P.s.: I already imported "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" and put "app.UseStaticFile()" on startup.cs.

Thank you in advance!
Valerio

Comment: Show the route configuration in your Startup.cs. I suspect you still have the default MVC route registered there, which redirects `/` to `/Home/Index`

Comment: @Tseng, actually, the Adem Caglin had the answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `app.UseDefaultFiles()` before `app.UseStaticFiles()`